# Magento 2 additional data to shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

I'm making new shipping method and I need to add new column to checkout shipping rates. Data would come from custom shipping method settings, for example method description. Or some input field where customer can add info (data probably would be saved in quote and later in order).

Probably the easiest part of all is implement template by using

```
Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

It just needs this

```
<div data-bind="text: method.description"></div>
```

Problem is I can't figure out how to add custom data. It's not enough to add this:

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->isActive()) return false;

    $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();
    $method->setData('carrier', $this->getCarrierCode());
    $method->setData('carrier_title', $this->getConfigData('title'));
    $method->setData('method_title', $this->getConfigData('title'));
    $method->setData('method', $this->getCarrierCode());
    $method->setPrice($this->_price);
    $method->setData('cost', $this->_price);

    // custom
    $method->setData('description', $this->getConfigData('description'));

    $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();
    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

Data for html comes from js rates(), which gets data from API:

```
<route url="/V1/carts/:cartId/shipping-methods" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface" method="getList"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

After this there are many steps while something actually gets collected.
I found

> Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter modelToDataObject()

that looked the most promising but if I try to add my attribute to it, nothing happens.

So my question is, if there actually is a way to add new data to shipping rates? In M1 it was possible. It would be crazy if M2 it wasn't possible.

There are many reasons why this should be possible. For example if I wanted to make pick up in store method with multiple stores drop down or something similar.

Comment: Hi , If you got the solution could you please share?

Comment: Well, any solution to this?

Comment: I'm waiting this answer.

Answer (score 18):

The top-rated answer doesn't work because he forgot to set the "description" value inside of the **\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate** class. If we do not create a Plugin to set the Description value on this class, then **$rateModel->getMethodDescription()** will always return empty. Here is a full-working version of the solution:

**[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface">
        <attribute code="description" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter">
        <plugin name="add_description_to_method" type="<Vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Carrier\Description" disabled="false" sortOrder="30"/>
    </type>

<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate">
        <plugin name="add_description_to_method_rate" type="<Vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Quote\Address\Rate" disabled="false" sortOrder="3"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Carrier/Description.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\module\Plugin\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterfaceFactory;


class Description
{
    /**
     * @var ShippingMethodInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * Description constructor.
     * @param ShippingMethodInterfaceFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ShippingMethodInterfaceFactory $extensionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param $rateModel
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterModelToDataObject($subject, $result, $rateModel)
    {
        $extensionAttribute = $result->getExtensionAttributes() ?
            $result->getExtensionAttributes()
            :
            $this->extensionFactory->create()
        ;
        $extensionAttribute->setDescription($rateModel->getDescription());
        $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttribute);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And finally:

**[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Quote/Address/Rate.php**

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Quote\Address;

class Rate
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\AbstractResult $rate
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate
     */
    public function afterImportShippingRate($subject, $result, $rate)
    {
        if ($rate instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method) {
            $result->setDescription(
                $rate->getDescription()
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Do not forget to run bin/magento setup:di:compile, otherwise the extended attribute won't be generated.**

You can bind the data to your template using this:

```
<div data-bind="text: method.extension_attributes.description"></div>
```

Or as a comment, like this:

```
<!-- ko text: $data.extension_attributes.description --><!-- /ko -->
```

Also do not forget to use **$method->setDescription('Your Custom Description Here')** or **$method->setData('description', 'Your custom Description Here')** inside of your custom Carrier extension (look at the original question for reference).

Comment: In latest version 2.3.4 ShippingMethodExtensionFactory need to update with ShippingMethodInterfaceFactory

Comment: @Jack Good spot, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 8):

You need to do this by adding description as an extension attribute as below:

/etc/extension_attributes.xml should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface">
        <attribute code="method_description" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

In the etc/di.xml file add a plugin for overriding modelToDataObject() in Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter">
        <plugin name="add_description_to_carrier" type="<Vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Carrier\Description" disabled="false" sortOrder="30"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The plugin file Vendor\module\Plugin\Carrier\Description.php should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\module\Plugin\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodExtensionFactory;

/**
 * Class Description
 * 
 */
class Description
{
    /**
     * @var ShippingMethodExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * Description constructor.
     * @param ShippingMethodExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ShippingMethodExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param $rateModel
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterModelToDataObject($subject, $result, $rateModel)
    {
        $extensionAttribute = $result->getExtensionAttributes() ?
            $result->getExtensionAttributes()
            :
            $this->extensionFactory->create()
        ;
        $extensionAttribute->setMethodDescription($rateModel->getMethodDescription());
        $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttribute);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

After all this you will get that description on fronend as below:

```
<div data-bind="text: method.extension_attributes.method_description"></div>
```

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the method names in interface file, the path for this file is

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Api/Data/ShippingMethodInterface.php
```

Example:
Declare constant at the top

```
const KEY_DESCRIPTION = 'description';
```

then define method as follows

```
public function getDescription();
public function setDescription($desc);
```

Then you need to assign values to the following file

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/ShippingMethod.php
```

as follows

```
public function getDescription()
{
  return $this->_get(self::KEY_DESCRIPTION);
}
public function setDescription($desc)
{
  return $this->setData(self::KEY_DESCRIPTION, $desc);
}
```

Comment: Adding method to public api (vendor/magento/module-quote/Api/Data/ShippingMethodInterface.php )??? Never do that.

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** In latest version 2.3.4 ShippingMethodExtensionFactory need to update with ShippingMethodInterfaceFactory